# pg_restore cant find the input file "X" no such directory or file

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin, pg-dump, pg-restore

first off im relatively new to pgadmin and postgresql

so i have a backup done with pgadmin in plain text which dumps the data i need from one table into a file called lodging. it came from a plans_to_lodge table from our live server. now to test a new web application front end i want to pg_restore it but this is what i get

```
> pg_restore -h localhost  -d TestingDatabase2 -t lodging_of_plans -n plan_authentication "C:\lodging"
pg_restore: [archiver] could not open input file "C:\lodging": No such file or directory
```

the documentation doesnt give an example for a table restore 
and yes the file is at that location in the C drive

Comment: what `dir "C:\lodging"` shows?..

Comment: @VaoTsun when i cd to root 
and use dir
i see the file im looking for

when i dir C:lodging it shows me the file and size

Comment: There does not seem to be a file called `C:\lodging` on the computer where you run `pg_restore`.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe i tried just lodging and same thing. no file or directory

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was it being the root folder, so when i put the file named lodging into another folder like so

```
C:\folder\lodging
```

it worked now onto more errors